# Tinymce-angular: Editor Full screen issue

Tags: css, angular, tinymce, scrollbar, tinymce-4

I'm using `<editor *ngIf="defaultContent" [(ngModel)]='defaultContent' [init]='editorConfig'>`

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular

this is my configuration below -

```
export const editorConfig = {
    skin_url: '/assets/skins/lightgray',
    theme: 'modern',
    content_css: targetElt.getAttribute('href'),
    height: 300,
    branding: false,
    // content_security_policy: 'script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\'; connect-src \'self\'; img-src \'self\';' +
    //     'style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
    plugins: 'textcolor anchor link lists wordcount fullscreen hr code table', // template
    hidden_input: false,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  |' +
    'numlist bullist outdent indent  | paste | section | row | info | fullscreen | template | removeformat |' +
    'undo redo | code | table',
    templates: [
        {
            title: 'Some title 1', description: 'Some desc 1', content: '<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="row widget-sd">' +
            '<div class="sd-img col-sm-3"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/321/321718.svg"></div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-9"></div></div></div>'
        }
    ],
    table_default_attributes: {
        'border': '0'
    },
    table_default_styles: {
        'border-collapsed': 'collapse',
        'width': '100%'
    },
    table_responsive_width: true,
    table_advtab: false
}
```

**When i click on editor full screen and then i click on browser back screen and again visited the editor screen then screen goes freeze, no scrollbar is appearing on my theme.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the .mce-fullscreen class on ngOnDestroy.

> document.body.className =
>   document.body.className.replace('mce-fullscreen', '');
>       $('html').removeClass('mce-fullscreen');